# Sets of operations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to know if my answers are all correct, if someone willing to check it it will be greatly appreciated ...Thanks!

Universal/Union = { a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

A = {a,b,c,d}             A' = {e,f,g,h}

B = {e,f,g,h}.             B' = {a,b,c,d}

C = {a,d,h}                C' = {b,c,e,f,g}

D = {c,d,f,g}              D' = {a,b,e,h}

E = {a,b,c,f,g,h}         E' = {d,e}

Sets:

1.)[ [ [(A' ∩ B')' ∩ (C' ∩ D')']' - [(B-D')'- (A-C')']' ]' - E ]'

2.) [ [ [ [ (A' - B')' -C' ]' - D' ]' - E' ]' ∩ [ ( A' ∪ B')' ∩ (E' ∩ D')' ]' ]' ∩ ( B' '- C' ')' '

3.)[ B' ∩ [ (B' ∪ C')' - ( D' ∩ D)' ] ' ]' ∩ [( E ∪ E')' ∩ (C' - E)']'

Answer no. 1

A' ∩ B' = { }

(A' ∩ B')' = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

C' ∩ D' = {b,e}

(C' ∩ D')' = {a,c,d,f,g,h}

(A' ∩ B')' ∩ (C' ∩ D')'= {a,c,d,f,g,h}

[(A' ∩ B')' ∩ (C' ∩ D')']' = { b,e}

B - D' = {f,g}

(B - D')' = {a,b,c,d,e,h}

A - C' = {a,d}

(A' - C')' = {b,c,e,f,g,h}

( B - D')' - (A - C')' = {a,d}

[(B - D')' - (A - C')']' = {b,c,e,f,g,h}

[( A' ∩ B')' ∩ (C' ∩ D')']' - [( B - D')' - (A - C')']' = { }

[[ (A' ∩ B')' ∩ (C' ∩ D')']' - [( B - D')' - (A - C')']']' = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

[[ (A' ∩ B')' ∩ (C' ∩ D')']' - [( B - D')' - (A - C')']']' - E = { e,d}

Final Answer:

[ [[ (A' ∩ B')' ∩ (C' ∩ D')']' - [( B - D')' - (A - C')']']' - E ]' = {a,b,c,f,g,h}

Answer no. 2

A' - B' = { }

(A' - B')' = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

(A' - B')' - C' = {a,d,h}

[(A' - B')' - C']' = {b,c,e,f,g}

[(A' - B')' - C']' - D' = {c,f,g}

[ [(A' - B')' - C']' - D' ]' = {a,b,d,e,h}

[ [(A' - B')' - C']' - D' ]' - E' = {a,b,h}

[ [ [(A' - B')' - C']' - D' ]' - E' ]' = {c,d,e,f,g}

A' ∪ B' = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

(A' ∪ B')' = { }

E' ∩  D' = {e}

(E' ∩ D')' = { a,b,c,d,f,g,h}

(A' ∪ B')' ∩ (E' ∩ D')' = { }

[(A' ∪ B')' ∩ (E' ∩ D')']' = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

[ [ [(A' - B')' - C']' - D' ]' - E' ]' ∩ [(A' ∪ B')' ∩ (E' ∩ D')']' = {c,d,e,f,g}

[ [ [ [(A' - B')' - C']' - D' ]' - E' ]' ∩ [(A' ∪ B')' ∩ (E' ∩ D')']' ] ' = {a,b,h}

*I cancel out  B' ' - C ' '

(B - C)' = {a,b,c,d,h}

[(B - C)']' = {e,f,g}

Final Answer:

[ [ [ [(A' - B')' - C']' - D' ]' - E' ]' ∩ [(A' ∪ B')' ∩ (E' ∩ D')']' ] ' ∩ [(B - C)']' = { }

Answer no. 3

B' ∪ C' = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g}

(B' ∪ C')' = {h}

D' ∩ D = { }

(D' ∩ D)' = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

(B' ∪ C')' - (D' ∩ D)' = { }

[(B' ∪ C')' - (D' ∩ D)']' ={ a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

B' ∩ [(B' ∪ C')' - (D' ∩ D)']' = {a,b,c,d}

[ B' ∩ [(B' ∪ C')' - (D' ∩ D)']' ]' ={e,f,g,h}

E ∪ E' = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

(E ∪ E')' = { }

C' - E = {e}

(C' - E)' = {a,b,c,d,f,g,h}

(E ∪ E')' ∩ (C' - E)' = { }

[ (E ∪ E')' ∩ (C' - E)' ] ' = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

Final Answer:

[ B' ∩ [(B' ∪ C')' - (D' ∩ D)']' ]' ∩ [ (E ∪ E')' ∩ (C' - E)' ] ' = { e,f,g,h}

Comment: Hi XELA_1998! Your work will be much easier to read and provide feedback on if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @eepperly16 Yes, I will next time! Thanks for the tips but I just wanna know if this is all correct? Please pass this, I'm new here sorry...

Comment: It's quite long so I haven't checked everything, but the pseudorandom sample I checked looks good :)

Comment: @eepperly16 Thank you for checking! Hope u can check it further if you have time :)

Comment: Your first Q contains no sentences. It is a list of things. This style of writing is like a puzzle for the reader: "See if you can figure out the most plausible meaning of this." Write math as you write anything else: Complete sentences with nouns & verbs & punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first part $(C’ \cap D’)’ = \{a,c,d,f,g,h \}$, a possible typo in the fourth line.

In the second part $A’-B’ = \{e,f,g,h\}$.

In the third part, you may have missed a complement after $(D’\cap D)$ in the question.

Comment: I finally get what i went wrong in the first part and the last part but in the second part, should I start all over again?

Comment: Hi! I already edited it in the second and the third part question but in the first part : [( A' ∩ B')' ∩ (C' ∩ D')']'  = {b,e}  And [( B - D')' - (A - C')']'  = {b,c,e,f,g,h}. So, [( A' ∩ B')' ∩ (C' ∩ D')']' - [( B - D')' - (A - C')']' = { }     ???

Comment: Wow! Really all three!? Thank you for helping me with this! Really appreciated!! 

Comment: The first and third are correct. In the second part, $(A’-B’)’-C’ = \{a,d,h\}$.

Comment: Hello! Does the second part finally correct?

Comment: Hey! I was wondering in the second part i use a  "-" which is a difference. That means A' - B' = {e,f,g,h} ?? It's A' = {e,f,g,h} and B' = {a,b,c,d} ??? I'm confuse right now..

Comment: But it's A' - B' not A -B it uses a complement operations and it's not using a intersection symbol, its difference....and why if intersection is a null the difference should be too? I thought they have a different functions?

Comment: If A' ∩ B' = { } cause it's intersection ( A' & B' should have a common element to make it not null) while A' - B' = { e,f,g,h} cause put a element that A' has but B' don't. ???

Comment: Oh, I am sorry @XELA_1998, you are right. $A’-B’ = A’ \cap B’’ = A’ \cap B = \{e,f,g,h\}$, not the empty set. Sorry again.

Comment: That's OK, At least I know how solve this..Thanks to you XD